# Creating a Java, XML application with Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, buildpath, eclipse-luna

How do I: insert a XML file into a Java application, and then compile/run?

Day one of using XML with Java.  I'm working through the code/syntax ok, but I can't figure on how to 'add' this .xml into my Java application and have the application run.

I'm using Window 8.1, eclipse Luna, Java SE 8. I've attempted a few different suggestions I've found online, but no luck.

On one of my attempts this was the error message, I'm not sure what the error message has been with all attempts, but I think it has been similar, if not the same.

I have also included the .java and .xml.  As far as I know, my issue could be anywhere, so I'm open to all suggestions.  But you'll probably have to walk me from the ground up on this one.

Thank you for your consideration and effort.

```html
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Reed\workspace\JavaXMLDOMParser\input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
 at javaXMLDOMParse.DomParserPuCm.main(DomParserPuCm.java:23)
```

```js
package javaXMLDOMParse;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class DomParserPuCm 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       try 
       { 
          File inputFile = new File("Input.xml");
          
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          
          DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          
          Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
          
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
          
          System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
          
          NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
          
          System.out.println("----------------------------");
          
          for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
          {
             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
             System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
             
             if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
             {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                
                System.out.println("Student roll no : " + eElement.getAttribute("rollno"));
                
                System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println("Marks : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("marks").item(0).getTextContent());
             }
          }
       } 
       catch (Exception e) 
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singn</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException: the file does not exist at the path you are supplying (C:\Users\Reed\workspace\JavaXMLDOMParser\input.txt)

Comment: got ya.  can you suggest/link any tutorials on setting up a project of this nature?

I checked a few out but the ones I viewed seemed all over the place and involved material/steps that I don't think i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got your `FileNotFoundException` because your program is not executed in the folder where the XML is located.
Just put your `Input.xml`next to your class and use `Document doc = Builder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Input.xml"));` to process the file. This way you do not need to care about the path.

Comment: So I edited my statement that declares doc with the above suggestion, and imported: java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry.Builder;  //  However, getting this error from getClass(): Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object  //  This is how the statement is currently:  Document doc = Builder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Input.xml"));

Comment: If you have no instance, just call DomParserPuCm.class.getResourceAsStream(...)

Comment: Sounds good.  Just did: Document doc = DomParserPuCm.class.getResourceAsStream("Input.xml");  //  Have this error message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from InputStream to Document

Comment: I forgott it's your first day of Java ;-)  Builder.parse(...) is the method that takes an InputStream and returns a Document. So the complete line is: Document doc=dBuilder.parse(DomParserPuCm.class.getResourceAsStream("Input.xml"));

Comment: lol, yeah. First day of mixing XML and Java, so until I can start working with/wrap my head around it, I'm swimming in it. Thanks BTW. So I think we are close, now have: Document doc = dBuilder.parse(DomParserPuCm.class.getResourceAsStream("Input.xml")); // No warnings or errors in editor, but when I run: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null // at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) // at javaXMLDOMParse.DomParserPuCm.main(DomParserPuCm.java:27) //  Here is my path to Index.xml: /JavaXMLDOMParser/src/javaXMLDOMParse/Index.xml

Comment: Well, Input.xml? or Index.xml? Having the name wrong gives this errror.